# Editor-Assignable function pointer in UE4 C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

So I have a TriggerBox that I'm using as a pressure pad, and I want to be able to attach objects to it that, when the TriggerBox is activated, will have specific functions called. Similar to unity's UI buttons, where you can assign a function to be called when the button is clicked.

I am working as the sole programmer, and the rest of my team are designers. They need to be able to assign the object's function to the TriggerBox from within the editor.

I have attempted to use C++'s function pointers, but I have not been able to find a way to make them assignable in the editor.

Is there a solution to this? If not, any suggestions on better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the function callable in Blueprint.  To do this, in the line above the function put in as follows:

UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="YourCategoryName")

This will tell Unreal that you want your function to be used inside the editor using the usual Blueprint chain with inputs and outputs.

A full list of things you can do with this is available here:
https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blueprints,_Creating_C%2B%2B_Functions_as_new_Blueprint_Nodes